# How can I check Oozie logs

Tags: hadoop, oozie

My coordinator failed with Error : E0301 invalid resource [filename]
when I do hadoop fs -ls [filename] the file is listed.

how can I debug what is wrong. 
how can I check log files???

oozie job -log requires jobId. in my case i dont have job id. how can I see logs in that case. appreciate responses.

thank you

Answer (score 9):

If you are looking for a command line way to do this, you can run the following:

```
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000 -info <wfid>
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000 -log <wfid>
```

If you have the $OOZIE_URL set, then you do not need the -oozie parm in the above statements.  This first command will show you the status of the job and each action.  The second command will dig into the oozie log and display the part in the log that pertains to the workflow id that was passed in.

Comment: Your answer only gives the syslog information from Oozie int the terminal. How to get the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` information which is what actually considered as log.

Answer (score 3):

```
cd /var/log/oozie/
ls
```

You should see the log file there.

Comment: I don't see oozie inside log

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using the oozie webconsole when new to oozie. If you are using Cloudera it's under "Enabling the Oozie Web Console" here http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_17_6.html for CDH4. CDH3 link is similar.

Also the jobid is printed when you submit the job.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response. I have the web console enabled but where can I see logs in it. The job id is not printed because the job was not successfully started. i get the error and it terminates. no job id

Comment: Do you have any jobs created for your workflow at http://HADOOP_CLUSTER:51111/jobhistoryhome.jsp ? Do you get this error from oozie CLI when you submit your coordinator or when it starts running your workflow?

Comment: its when i run the coordinator. running the workflow is fine. thanks

Comment: does the filename in your hadoop fs -ls [filename] starts with hdfs:// ? Try to run 'echo ${filename}' from workflow.xml before hadoop command to see the value